# Cannot read property 'username' of undefined in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to access `user` object inside of the `for` loop but I get the error.

```
User.find({resume :{$ne : null}}, (err,user)=>{
if(err) res.send('ther is some problem for updating resumes') ;
if(user){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < user.length ; i++){
        Like.count({for : user[i].username }, (err,count)=>{
            if(err) res.send('there is something wrong with counting likes');
            console.log('inside: ' + user[i].username);

        })
    }
}
})
```

user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose') ; 

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
username : {
    type : String,
    require : true
},
password : {
    type : String,
    require : true ,
},
resume : {
    type : String
},
date : {
    type : Date,
    default : Date.now()
}
})

module.exports= mongoose.model("user",schema) ;
```

I can't firgure out what is wrong !

Comment: Can you share your User mongoose model?

Comment: sure @ChadMoore I edit it

Comment: did this help?? See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.find({ resume: { $ne: null } }, (err, users) => {
  if (err) res.send('there is some problem for updating resumes');
  //for debugging, temporarily log number of users found...
  console.log(`${users.length} were found with no resume!`);
  if (users.length > 0) {
    users.forEach((user) => {
      Like.count({ for: user.username }, (err, count) => {
        if (err) res.send('there is something wrong with counting likes');
        console.log('inside: ' + user.username);

      })
    });
  }
});
```

Pointers

- users is an array, you cannot check for falsy on array with `if (array)`, because empty arrays are truthy. So check the length `if (array.length > 0`.
- this wasn't your problem, but it's safer to use native array methods than your own for loops., e.g. `users.forEach`... instead of `for (var i = 0; ...`.